# Custom domain/URL in OneDrive

Tags: sharepoint, firewall, onedrive, cloud-storage

Our organization is looking for a cloud solution and we have looked at OneDrive. Currently we have a restriction with OneDrive where we want to give our clients access to our oneDrive for certain tasks. But for some client's one drive is blocked by the firewall. If we go for oneDrive business then will we be able to have our domain name instead of oneDrive.com.

Or is their a way that we can setup one drive features in our network.

Thanks in advance for the response.

Comment: You can also use Google Cloud Storage, you should give it a try and check wheather it suits your requirement or not.

Answer (score 3):

OneDrive is a cloud service, like Google, Dropbox, Box, etc. If someone has blocked it in their firewall, there isn't much that can be done. Many enterprises block these consumer-focused services because they don't want business files leaving their business networks.

Using OneDrive for Business would enable you to have your own domain, which hopefully your clients wouldn't block, and would meet the usual security requirements of enterprises. You could also use SharePoint or a file share to host the files on your network, but then your clients won't be able to access them directly either.

Comment: Can i have the same functionality if i set office web app server in my local network. Will it provide embedded excel feature.